Help identifying a pattern
I was playing in codingame and got a strange challenge that I couldn't solve. There are 5 examples given and we need to identify what is the logic used. Each time we are provided with two entries, the first is an integer number and the second is a sequence of integers. The expected output is another integer number
The examples are the following:
Test 1
Input:
2
1 1
Output:
4
Test 2
Input:
3
2 2 2
Output:
27
Test 3
Input:
3
2 1 1
Output:
12
Test 4
Input:
5
5 2 2 1 1
Output:
216
Test 5
Input:
3
5 4 3
Output:
120
I have tried many math operations and haven't come up with a solution. I'm starting to doubt that it is a mathematical solution or that there is actually a solution, but I would love a second opinion from experts on this.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If the input $k$ numbers are $n_1,\ldots,n_k$ then the output seems to be $(n_1+1)\cdots(n_k+1).$
For example, $5, 4, 3 \to (5+1)(4+1)(3+1) = 6\cdot5\cdot4 = 120.$
Here's a C++ program implementing this:
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned k;
    std::cin >> k;

    unsigned result = 1;
    for (int i=0; i<k; i++) {
        unsigned nk;
        std::cin >> nk;
        result *= (nk+1);
    }

    std::cout << result;

    return 0;
}

https://godbolt.org/z/ss94sWzvf
Python 3:
k = int(input())

result = 1
for nk in map(int, input().split()):
    result *= (nk+1)

print(result)

https://godbolt.org/z/EEs3h4aq8

+1. With the added fact that the initial integer gives the length of the following sequence

@jonnybolton16. Of course. I just thought that that was known, but perhaps that wasn't obvious even for Mateo.

Agreed it's pretty obvious, but since Mateo didn't mention it, maybe they didn't spot it.
